# add, update markers/bookmarks to JwPlayer

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I'm trying to add markers/bookmarks dynamically to the jwplayer like:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The best way is using the [addCues](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jwplayer/docs/jw8-javascript-api-reference#section-jwplayer-addcues-cues-):

```
function addBookmark() {
 var currentTimeRound = Math.round(vid.currentTime);
 var resultBookMark = cues.find(function(element) {
  return element.begin === currentTimeRound;
 });
 if(!resultBookMark){
  bookmarkList.push(currentTimeRound);
  var newBookmark = [{begin: currentTimeRound, text: "New bookmark"}];
  playerInstance.addCues(newBookmark);
 }
}
```